# Sum of number of divisors

Tags: number-theory

What is the value of d(1) + d(2) + d(3) + ... + d(99)?

Here d(x) denotes the number of positive divisors of x including 1 and x.

For example, positive divisors of 4 are 1, 2, and 4 so d(4)= 3.

Comment: You want the $\sigma_1$ function, see at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) for interesting properties and Hardy and Wright's [book](http://archive.org/details/AnIntroductionToTheTheoryOfNumbers-4thEd-G.h.HardyE.m.Wright). the answer from pari/gp is 156.

Comment: No, that's not what I want [according to the link you gave me]. σ1(99) is the sum of divisors of 99, but I want the sum of number of divisors of integers from 1 to 99.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Can we use that $d$ is multiplicative? i.e., that $d(ab)=d(a)d(b)$ iff $(a,b)=1$?

Comment: Also: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum_1%5E%7B99%7D+sigma_0%28n%29

Although I would assume that you are looking for an analytic solution.

Comment: But σ0(6) gives the number of divisors of 99.

To put it your way, I want the value of σ0(1) + σ0(2) + ... + σ0(99).

Comment: @user47805 

Yes but WolframAlpha does brute force calculations. A nice mathematical solution would be great. Please help me.

Comment: Yes you are right... Sorry (I was wrong two times here...) I got 473. Are you wishing a general formula?

Comment: @Raymond Manzoni 

A general formula would be great, but currently I want a mathematical solution to the problem. I will try to build the general formula myself if I can solve this.

Comment: H&W propose this approximate formula for $n$ terms : $n\ln(n)+(2\gamma-1)n+O(\sqrt{n})$ at page $264$ because the average order of $d(n)$ is $\log(n)$ (for $n=99$ it returns around $470.2$). Anyway Ivan Loh (+1) gave you the exact answer $\sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor \frac nk\rfloor$ so that I'll stop here.

Comment: @Raymond Manzoni Thanks, but could you please explain the meaning of γ and the function O(x)? Thanks.

Comment: $\gamma\approx 0.57721566$ is the [Euler constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Mascheroni_constant) and $O(\sqrt{n})$ means that the error made is of order $\sqrt{n}$. See [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). In summary you'll have to add $n$ terms or use an approximate function as the one provided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Each number $n$ is the divisor of $n, 2n, \ldots n\lfloor \frac{99}{n} \rfloor$, and is thus counted $\lfloor \frac{99}{n} \rfloor$ times when you sum the number of divisors. Now sum over $n=1, 2, \ldots , 99$.

Comment: Okay, I am following your hint. Please correct me if I am wrong. 
My approach is in next comment.

Comment: Please wait a little. I think I am able to solve it, just checking it.

Comment: The number 1 is calculated [99/1]= 99 times. 
The number 2 is calculated [99/2]= 49 times.
The number 3 is calculated [99/3]= 33 times.
The number 4 is calculated [99/4]= 24 times.
The number 5 is calculated [99/5]= 19 times.
The number 6 is calculated [99/6]= 16 times.
The number 7 is calculated [99/7]= 14 times.
The number 8 is calculated [99/8]= 12 times.
The number 9 is calculated [99/9]= 11 times.
The number 10 is calculated [99/10]= 9 times.
The number 11 is calculated [99/11]= 9 times.
Rest is in the next comment.

Comment: This way I summed it. The answer is 473.

Comment: @abcd Looks correct. (You didn't have to keep writing "The number $n$ is calculated $[99/n]$ times" though. Just explain this at the start, then concentrate on summing.)

Comment: Okay. Thanks very much for the hint.